# Missing msdatasrc assembly reference

Tags: dependencies, .net-assembly

An old project has a bad path for this reference, all I have is the name msdatasrc.

There are a ton of sites offering free downloads of the .dll, but they all look shady.

Where is the msdatasrc.dll file typically located?

Where can it be retrieved from if it is not present on a device?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The assembly was located for me at 
`C:\Windows\assembly\GAC\MSDATASRC\7.0.3300.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\msdatasrc.dll`

The online kb328912 download is unfortunately no longer available.

It can be located in VS2017 installations at the following path

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies`

Comment: For future SOers, note if you install VS 2017 as of 2019, there is a new version of `msdatasrc.dll` that will not play nicely with projects that require `7.0.3300.0`.

Answer (score 0):

Provided MSDN link is dead, found it in [Primary Interop Assemblies](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18346).

Comment: thanks, I updated my answer to remove the dead link. 

It might be useful to put where the Primary Interop Assemblies places the .dll for projects that need to reference it

Comment: Well the installer requires that office 2007 is installed, so as a workaround I unpacked it and found the dll that way. Unfortunately I cannot give the exact location via the installer .. I imagine somewhere under program files and PIA.